# Find the cardinality of $S=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 2x+3y<5\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Find the cardinality of $S=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : 2x+3y<5\}$.

**Attempt:**

I graphed this set, and I noticed that the simpler set $(0,1)^2=B\subset S$, and I thought these two sets had the same cardinality, so I tried to find two injections, there's the easy one $id:(0,1)^2\to S/id:(x,y)\mapsto(x,y)$, but I couldn't find a reverse one...

Besides this problem, can you guys give me some general tips on how to solve these type of problems? Another example is "Find the cardinality of $A=\{graphs\}$.

Comment: $(0,1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$, which is also isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: All you need is that the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same as $\mathbb{R}$ which is the same as $(0,1)$. To make this as clean as possible, you may have to use the fact that if there are two injections going each way between two sets $A$ and $B$, then $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: I haven't gotten that result yet ($|\Bbb R^n|=c$). Is there any simple proof for that?

Comment: Maybe I don't even need that result, I can say $|\Bbb R \times \Bbb R|=|\Bbb R|\cdot |\Bbb R|=c\cdot c = |(0,1)|\cdot |(0,1)|=|(0,1)^2|$,  right?

So I end up getting (by an injection from S to $\Bbb R^2$): $|(0,1)^2)|\leq |S| \leq |\Bbb R^2|$)

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Sure, if you have a proof of that last statement in the chain then that is perfectly fine too =)

Comment: I just realized I end up getting $|S|=c\cdot c$, so I need your result anyway... Could you explain why your mapping is a bijection?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD you have an injection $S \to {\mathbb R}^2$. And hopefully you know there is a bijection $f:(0,1) \to {\mathbb R}$. So now all you need is injection $f:(0,1)^2 \to (0,1)$. For this, simply take a number $(x_1,x_2) \in (0,1)$ and take the digits of each number, and map it to the number $y$ where all the odd-indexed digits of $y$ are $x_1$ and all the even-indexed digits of $y$ are $x_2$. Technically you have to deal with the fact that you may have an infinite string of digits that rounds to the next number, but this can only happen on a countable set so everything is fine.

Comment: I think I inderstand, if $x_1=d_1d_2d_3...$ and $x_2=e_1e_2e_3...$ the mapping would be $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto (0,d_1e_1d_2e_2...$ right? If I understood correctly and this is the case, why is this injective? I'm sorry, but this subject is really hard for me.